# ionic framework: Setting property of slidebox from controller

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a slidebox for which I dont want the paging to be seen in the first screen so I added as below:

```
<ion-slide-box show-pager ="false" on-slide-changed="reportSlideChanged($index, $ionicSlideBoxDelegate)" >
```

However, I want to change the show-pager in the reportSlideChanged function when the index becomes greater than 0. I tried

```
.controller('SplashController', function ($scope, $ionicSlideBoxDelegate) {
    //$scope.myActiveSlide = 1;
    console.log($scope.currentSlide, $ionicSlideBoxDelegate)

    $scope.reportSlideChanged = function (slideNum) {
        $scope.showPager = true;
        $ionicSlideBoxDelegate.update()
    }
})
```

But this does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Hope this will help.

CSS

```
.no-pager .slider-pager{
   display: none;
}
```

Controller

```
$scope.pager = true;

$scope.togglePager = function(){
   $scope.pager = !$scope.pager;
};
```

HTML

```
<ion-slide-box show-pager="true" ng-class="{'no-pager':pager}">
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NPvmjB